# How to access public variables of another (referenced) VBA project without using the code name as qualifier

Tags: excel, vba

I try to access public variables in other Excel files (which are referenced) without hard coding the excel file/VBA project and need help in achieving this. I need the qualification as multiple files with similar variables can be open.

Assume you have a VBA project `Test(Test.xlsb)` which defined a public variable `myVar`.

In another VBA project (which has a reference to `Test`) I can access this variable , e.g.

```
debug.print Test.myVar
```

However I have been unable to achieve the same without using the qualifier `Test`. I tried to use a`workBook`, `VBProject` and `Reference` as qualifier but none of these options works out. I also cannot assign the object addressed by the code name to a variable. The code `set myObj = Test` throws a compiler error, while `set mySheet = Test.Sheet1` does work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to define the public variable outside of the module, so to be placed in the worksheet object, outside of any functions.

A similar question is asked here [Using Excel VBA variable for multiple workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780945/using-excel-vba-variable-for-multiple-workbooks)

So, if you place `Public myVar as String` (assumng the type is string) in the external workbooks' `ThisWorkbook` and set your object to the workbook as you have been doing, you can then achieve this:

```
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsb")
 MsgBox wb.myVar
```

Comment: Thx. Your approach seems to be working. It does, however, not work for custom datatypes, as I cannot define them in an object module (sigh).

Comment: Yes, I think you might struggle with that one. If there are regular types that you wish to extract from your custom type, could you create a sub in the child workbook (e.g. `Sub SetGlobalVars()`) that gets your required variables and allocates them to variables of regular type in ThisWorkbook, then call this procedure from your parent one using `Application.Run "'Test.xlsb'!SetGlobalVars"` first. You can then reference the allocated variables using the original method above.